# List of running application on remote machines using powershell

Tags: powershell

I can access the remote machines. I can even use get-process cmdlet to get the list of running process in remote machines. What I am unable to do is to get the list of running applications on remote machines.
This is not a problem for local machine where I can use the following cmdlet

```
get-process | where-object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} | select-object name, mainwindowtitle
```

But the problem is with remote pc where this gives an empty result. I have searched a lot on this topic and found that mainwindowhandle doesn't work in remote machines.

So, I would  be highly oblidged if you provide me with a solution.

Comment: do you mean a completely empty result, or just MainWindowTitle missing? `get-process -ComputerName RemoteComputer | where-object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} | select-object name, mainwindowtitle` gives me results for processes, but not for MainWindowTitle

Comment: I get a complete empty result @SimonS. It seems that $_. mainwindowhandle is always equal to 0 for remote pcs. So how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: @RajDeb - the session on the remote system is NON-interactive ... so there otta not be any windows to look at. [*grin*] if you want to see what the current user is running, the simplest way i know of is to set up a run-once task that runs as the currently logged in user.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Sorry, but I didn't get what you are saying. Can you please explain it or give me a code? I need it for my project work and I am new to powershell.

Comment: interactive sessions are what you use when you run code directly on your system. the windows are the GUI ... and only exist in an interactive session. remote sessions are NOT interactive ... so they don't have a GUI ... and don't have windows ... and thus don't have window titles. ///// look up `run once task` and `run as current logged on user` for how to get the app list for a logged on user on a remote system.

Answer (score 1):

`mainwindowhandle` won't work because the powershell session you're using to check doesn't actually have any "windows" open. You can only see windows **you** have open, but **not** windows opened by another user on the system for example.

Try this command to see who is actually logged into the remote machine:

```
quser /server:MyServerName

 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 you                   rdp-tcp#88          1  Active          .  8/14/2020 11:41 AM
 user2                                     2  Disc            .  8/14/2020 10:00 AM
```

And then get the processes belonging to that user's `SessionID` specifically:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_Process -ComputerName MyServerName -Property Name,SessionID | 
  Where SessionID -EQ 1 | 
  Select Name,SessionID

Name              SessionID
----              ---------
explorer.exe              1
powershell.exe            1
notepad.exe               1
[etc.]
```

This will return more than just open windows, but there is no way to tell which processes have a window open since Windows isolates this information between sessions (except when running a remote desktop server/RDS Host).

When you are checking remotely, windows creates a new tiny session with only one (hidden) window titled 'WSMan Provider Host'. You can learn more using the `User32` code written [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2onpdm/get_active_window_titles_of_remote_computer/) by reddit user u/LandOfTheLostPass

Comment: Thanks a lot @user19702

Comment: "Get-WmiObject" is now deprecated in PowerShell 7.x. Use "Get-CimInstance" instead.